# Odoo 13: How to do do ajax call in Odoo?

Tags: jquery, ajax, odoo

I'm working on filters in custom page in **odoo website** (use form > select > option).
In order to do that, I tried to make ajax call to send/receive datas without reloading the page (a custom one) in odoo website.
I tested multiple codes, but none of them work.
Here is my controllers :

```
@http.route([
    '/trainers',
], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def trainers(self, **post):
    partner_obj = request.env['res.partner']

    partners = partner_obj.sudo().search([('trainer', '=', True), ('show_trainer', '=', True)])

    values = {
        'partners': partners,
        'categs': request.env['training.catalogue'].search([], order="sequence"),
        'current_page': 3,
    }
    return request.render("website_training.trainer", values)
```

I tried with this jquery code :

```
odoo.define('website_training.trainers', function (require) {
"use strict";

var ajax = require('web.ajax');

$('#trainer-catlg li').click(function () {
    $('#search-catlg').val($(this).attr("value"));
    ajax.jsonRpc("/trainers", 'call', {
        'catalg': $('#search-catlg').val(),
    });
});
});
```

And got this error : Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'
My second try is with this code:

```
$('#trainer-catlg li').click(function () {
    $('#search-catlg').val($(this).attr("value"));
    var data = {
        'catalg': $('#search-catlg').val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/trainers",
        data: data,
        success: null,
    });
});
```

With this last one, the controller is not even called (I seted a breakpoint in the controller for testing purpose).
Can you help me? Is there another way to do that?
Another option is to play with "display: none" with jquery and css to make filters, but I think this is not good for performance when data is big.

Comment: For the first one you declared the type of request `http` but you used `jsonRpc` witch send a request of type `json`, if you go with json request odoo require a sertain structure of the data of request i think ut must contains params attribute, you google it.

Comment: Check this it may help you: stackoverflow.com/questions/58855693/send-json-data-for-json-get-request-in-odoo-12

Comment: @CharifDZ I already check the link, when I changed type="http" to "json", I got error when rendering the template (json object doesn't have render ...). So how to use both, I want to render the page and sent data.

Comment: Build another controller with type="json". Finally, I will play with css class and jquery. Thanks

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: @CharifDZ, really sorry for the longing. Here is the jquery code for the filters : https://pastebin.com/tmy9BUJr